# How to add elements to an array that is a property of an object in PHP?

Tags: php, html, arrays, object

I would like to be able to have an object which contains an array as a property. I would like to be able to add elements to that array. I get the errors: Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /wwwg32Np9 on line 18 vw1997Array (I am running this in w3schools demo pages)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
class Car {
    public $model; 
    public $year; 
    public $passengers;

    function __construct() {
        $this->model = "";
        $this->year = " ";
        $this->passengers=array(); //?not sure if this is right
    }
//wrote a function to see if I could add elements to the array this way

function addPassengers($passenger)
    {
        array_push($passengers, $passenger); 
        return $passengers; 
    }
}
// create an object
$herbie = new Car(); 
$herbie->model = "vw"; 
$herbie->year = "1997"; 
$herbie->addPassengers("Mike"); //? is this right? 

// show object properties
echo $herbie->model;
echo $herbie->year; 
echo $herbie->passengers;  //?is this right? 
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `echo $herbie->passengers;` needs to be `print_r($herbie->passengers);`

Comment: Inside `addPassengers` you need to use `$this->passengers`, not `$passengers`, Other than that and @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie comment, everything is fine.

Comment: Was just going to say that @Nick. Object properties aren't "global vars" in behavior. They need `$this` for scope in methods.

Comment: As a long term thing, I would recommend looking at making properties of classes as either private or protected.  This is to protect against random changes being made to properties and potentially making them nonsense (i.e. making `$year` = 'sometime soon')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do 2 changes:

1.Use `$this->passengers` inside function.

2.Use `print_r()` to print it

```
<?php

class Car {
    public $model; 
    public $year; 
    public $passengers;

    function __construct() {
        $this->model = "";
        $this->year = " ";
        $this->passengers=array();
    }

function addPassengers($passenger)
    {
        array_push($this->passengers, $passenger); 
        return $this->passengers; 
    }
}

$herbie = new Car(); 
$herbie->model = "vw"; 
$herbie->year = "1997"; 
$herbie->addPassengers("Mike");


echo $herbie->model;
echo $herbie->year; 
print_r($herbie->passengers);
?>
```

Output:- https://3v4l.org/aQn2h

***Note:-*** You can write less amount of code and get the same output: https://3v4l.org/KTVAp

***As other comments stated you need to use `private variables` instead of public***

Sample example: -https://3v4l.org/8RF9j